# Guidelines for editing tag wiki excerpts

Tags: discussion, tags

Just went on a little tag-wiki edit-spree, and then realized that pretty much half my edits, despite being useful (the tags had no wiki whatsoever), were mostly **defining *what* the tag is about**.

### Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: The better our tag wikis, the clearer CR's scope. Tag wiki excerpts are like an extension of the help center /FAQ, they help askers knowing what's on-topic and what's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, it's not.

Tag wiki excerpts should not *just* say *what* - they *can* describe *what* a tag is about, but more importantly they should say *why* - **why** someone should be using a given tag *in the context of asking for a code review*, and **why** someone would want to follow a given tag.

Here's a glimpse of an [article from Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) that I saw about halfway through my editing spree:

> Here’s a few words of advice on writing tag wiki excerpts:
>
> 1. **The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.** You only have ~500
>      plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to
>      cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown
>      tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions
>      containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences.
> 2. **Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly
>      specialized.** The “email” tag, for example, does not need to explain
>      what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet users know
>      what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate explanation of email
>      to anyone.
> 3. **Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.** For
>      “email” on Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including
>      POP3, SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User,
>      mention desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that
>      would be more appropriate for webapps.stackexchange.com.
> 4. **Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.** In other words, what kinds of
>      questions should have this tag? Tags only exist as ways of organizing
>      questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which questions
>      need this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the tag excerpt
>      moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a room full of tags screaming
>      “pick me!”, what would convince a question asker to select your tag?
> 5. **Some tags are common knowledge.** Most tags require a bit of explanation
>      in the excerpt, even if it’s only 3 or 4 words. But if the tag is
>      common knowledge — that is, if you walked up to any random person on
>      the street and said the tag word to them, and they would know what you
>      were talking about — then don’t bother explaining the tag at all.
>      Stick to usage of the tag within your community in the excerpt.

Amen.

<sub>I first wanted to post this as a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) "question", but then realized it was more of a statement/answer, so I reworded it to make it fit the QA format :)</sub>